# Working on a project on codeacademy, nested if statements

Tags: python

[image: http://imgur.com/tyETg3M]

Here's a screen shot of what I have to do.
I'm really confused, and have no idea where to start.

Any tips?

Comment: Taking a screenshot of code is against the recommendations of this site, also it probably takes 10X as long as just COPY-Paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pig Latin, if the word starts with a consonant, then it moves to the end of the string, and you add "ay", right?

Let's say my input is `banana`. Now, with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
banana[0] == 'b'
banana[1:] == 'anana'
```

Now try figure it out from here :)